# Can I add manually getter and setter method in symfony entity ?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

Also add the specific column directly in the database table  instead of using the command to generate entities provided in symfony ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add the new column inside your Entity

Then added getter and setter methods inside Entity class.

Then do php `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` from console.